# Excel - updating linked cells from the clone

Tags: microsoft-excel

I work with a pricing spreadsheet, which has hundreds of inputs, but in reality I only tend to work with 5 or 6.

I want to create a summary worksheet where I only have the inputs I want to manipulate frequently all together. Essentially, i'd want to clone the cells I use commonly, update them on the summary sheet and they'd also be updated in their original locations that I'd linked from.

Is there any way to do this? Cell linking doesn't seem to offer this functionality - i.e. it's read only.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked into using an [external data connection](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-edit-and-manage-connections-to-external-data-89d44137-f18d-49cf-953d-d22a2eea2d46)? You can have it refresh every minute, so any changes you make will be near-realtime

Comment: I haven't, but that seems to be a long way round it. Essentially I just want to create a linked clone, so I can update either cell and it will reflect in the other.

Comment: Yes that would be the standard way to do it, make an external cell reference. Have you tried that? It sounded like in your question that didn't work

Comment: It's a bit difficult for me to understand from your question exactly how your data is split between the two spreadsheets. Maybe post an example/screenshot how it looks

Comment: @superhands, could you share some sample data with us & the look of the Summary Sheet, will help us to fix the issue in better way !! ☺

Comment: My suggestion is use `INDIRECT` function.

Comment: " I just want to create a linked clone" <--- that is what the proposed [external data connection](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-edit-and-manage-connections-to-external-data-89d44137-f18d-49cf-953d-d22a2eea2d46) **actually** does. Have a try and share with us how it solve / partially solves your need. || a sample data/file/screenshot would do..